# Accessing TextBox Text Inside GridView (C# / XAML)

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app

So I have a customised GridView with a data template that contains a TextBox and is populated by a list of a custom class called Player. I need to be able to retrieve both the instance of Player and the text in the TextBox and save them to a new custom class called Score.

```
    <GridView x:Name="gridScore" ItemsSource="{x:Bind PlayerList}" IsItemClickEnabled="True">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Player">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBox x:Name="txtbxGridScore" TextChanged="txtbxGridScoreChangedEventHandler" />
                    <Image Source="{x:Bind ProfilePicture}"/>
                    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind FullName}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Alias}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
    <Button x:Name="buttonSave" Content="Save Scores" Style="{StaticResource BarButtonStyle}" Click="buttonSave_Click"/>
```

I come from a web-based Java background so this is a little bit new to me but it seems like it should be a fairly simple exercise.

Initially, I tried iterating through the GridView upon a Button Click and grabbing each Player item along with the TextBox Text and saving them to a List<> of Score, however, getting the TextBox value proved troublesome.

I then tried initialising a page scope List<> of Score and simply updating it each time the TextBox value was changed, however, I wasn't able to make this work either.

A solution for either approach will work fine for my purposes. Any input is appreciated!

Comment: Can you say for what reason you want value of TextBox? To be clear in what scenario you want to get the value of it.

Comment: Sure! The value is the the score that the player got. So the app shows a list of all the current players and then the user inputs the score that each player got.

Comment: So you want to input score for players through the text box above?

Comment: And also can you edit your post to show us model class Player that you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understood you this is one of the way to resolve your problem.

So let's assume that your model class Player have this structure:

```
public class Player {

    public int PlayerID { get; set; }
    public string ProfilePicture { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Alias { get; set; }

    public float PlayerScore { get; set; } // To store textbox value
}
```

So you can resolve this by using **two way** binding.

XAML part will look something like this:

```
 <GridView x:Name="gridScore"
                  ItemsSource="{x:Bind PlayerList}"
                  IsItemClickEnabled="True">

            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Player">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBox x:Name="txtbxGridScore"
                                 Text="{x:Bind PlayerScore, Mode=TwoWay}" />

                        <Image Source="{x:Bind ProfilePicture}" />
                        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind FullName}" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Alias}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        </GridView>
        <Button x:Name="buttonSave"
                Content="Save Scores"
                Click="buttonSave_Click" />
```

I have initialized your PlayerList with some dummy data like this:

```
PlayerList = new ObservableCollection<Player>() {

            new Player() {
                FullName = "Player A", Alias = "AAA"
            },

            new Player () {
                FullName = "Player B", Alias = "BBB"
            }
};
```

As you can see in XAML I am binding your text box with PlayerScore property of Player model.

When I run this App I get screen like this:

[image]

I will input some data into TextBox and click Save button:
[image]

When I click on Save it will trigger the event that you wrote in Button part

In that event I have one foreach loop that will iterate through the list and one breakpoint and as you can see on first item "Player A" the PlayerScore value is 10:

[image]

Now you can find your players with some ID property or with some other way that you want. This is the most simple way to accomplish what you want.

**Remark**: This could be solved in a better way using MVVM pattern and other stuff but as you mentioned you are beginner so maybe it is better for you to solve it like this and after that go with more advanced technique. Hope that this was helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks for your help! 

Although this particular solution assumes that the value of the TextBox is going into a property of the Player class instead of a completely separate class of Score I was able to get it working with a small (albeit little bit messy) workaround. I created a new Temporary class with properties of both Player and Score and then bound my GridView to a list of this class. Then when it comes time to save I have access to both a Player and Score that belong to each other and I can do with them as I please. 

Good enough for me! Thanks again!

Comment: Yes that is another way to accomplish that. I am glad to hear that my answer was helpful for you. Best regards!